# Stop mongos process

Tags: mongodb

May be a dumb question,

In a sharded database configuration, I launched my mongos with the following command :

```
mongos --configdb config1:27019,config2:27019,config3:27019
```

I now need to stop mongo to enable internal Authentification and use a .conf file, problem is, whereas I can just do a `systemctl stop mongod` under the other config/shard servers, mongos behave differently.

`ps aux | grep mongo` give me this :

```
root      5200  0.4  1.3 317544 13588 ?        Sl   Dec30   6:01 mongos --config /etc/mongos.conf
```

I don't want to kill the process and risking making a mess, is there a way to gently stop mongos?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Log on to the `mongos`, run `use admin`, then `db.shutdownServer()` to gracefully shut down the `mongos` and leave the shards running.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to stop

```
mongod --dbpath /path/to/your/db --shutdown
```

**or**

To shut down a specific mongod instance use below command:

```
kill mongod process ID
```

**WARNING**:

```
Never use kill -9 (i.e. SIGKILL) to terminate a mongod instance.
```

Comment: I was trying to stop mongos, not mongod, but thanks anyway